# Metric that makes distribution orthogonal to each other

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, submanifold

Let $M$ be a manifold and $Q\subseteq M$ a submanifold. Suppose that there is an integrable distribution (sub-bundle) $E$ of $TM|_Q$ such that $TM|_Q=TQ\bigoplus E$. Can we guarantee a (Riemannian) metric $g$ on $M$ such that $E=TQ^\perp$?

Comment: Just patch them locally.

Comment: I thought about that, but metrics are not uniquely definied by orthogonality: there can be locally defined metrics $g_i$, $i=0,1$ such that $E=TQ^\perp$ but $g_0\neq g_1$. So, when you patch the metrics they won't agree on the intersections

Comment: I mean find a partition of unity subordinate to a collection of local trivialisation charts on $Q$, and patch using this partition of unity.  Finally extend to whole of $M$.